# Hibernate criteria multiple projection tied to a custom POJO

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Error

```
  Hibernate: select this_.UID as y0_, this_.PATH as y1_, this_.NAME as y2_ from AWARD this_ where this_.DELETED=?
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

Hibernate code

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("deleted", 0));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("uid"))
                .add(Projections.property("path")).add(Projections.property("name"))).
        setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AwardsInSession.class));

        List<AwardsInSession>  la = criteria.list();
```

Custorm POJO

```
public class AwardsInSession extends BaseModel{
   private String uid;

   private String path;

   private String name;
```

In JPA entity these 3 are of string type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it , The below code works. As we are using  Transformers.aliasToBean , each column in the criteria buildup should have an alias

```
criteria
            .add(Restrictions.eq("deleted", Boolean.FALSE))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("orgId.id", orgId))
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property("path"), "path"))
                    .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property("uid"), "uid"))
                    .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property("name"), "name")))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AwardsInSession.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Award entity, you have the `deleted` property field defined as Boolean.

Thus your restriction should be:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("deleted", Boolean.FALSE));
```

Comment: Thanks man got rid of the exception, but I couldn't get the values in to List<AwardsInSession>

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: There is no exception but all the values in AwardsInSession are null. This query is supposed to return 1 row

Comment: criteria
    .add(Restrictions.eq("deleted", Boolean.FALSE))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("orgId.id", orgId))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("path"))
    .add(Projections.property("name")).add(Projections.property("uid")))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AwardsInSession.class));
  
  if(orgId > 0){
   List<AwardsInSession>  la = criteria.list();

Comment: What is the database type of deleted column?